# Oozie to launch HQL files

Tags: hql, oozie

Heelo Community
I am working in a big data project and I have the following question :

I am willing to use oozie to run hql files in order to ceate tables and load data into them, I am currently using a hortonworks cluster xith 6 nodes  , my question is as follows 
Do I need to store my HQL files which have very small size under hdfs or may I use the local file system of the cluster. 
In the second case will oozie be able to  work with these files if they are under local file system. I am currently convinced that we shl=ould avoid storing small files under HDFS as much as possible. 
Thanks a lot for your reponses

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, Oozie requires everything except the job.properties file on HDFS.

Comment: Yes, oozie reads and localizes everything from HDFS. You should avoid storing small files on HDFS in general, but a couple of script, hql and workflow file should not cause any issues.

Comment: Yes, HDFS should be used for large size data but currently, Oozie takes data from HDFS. What we can try to run ssh action through Oozie which will take data from local file system.